# JPA - Is there a way/method to retrieve Persistence Unit information

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'd like to find out my data source name in the code. Is there a way of doing that?
I am using eclipselink.

thanks
To be more specific, my aim is to get an jdbc connection object.
I know i can do that thru:

```
datasource = (DataSource) (new InitialContext()).lookup("my_data_source_name")
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

But I don't want to hard code the data source name in my code.

I also tried

```
java.sql.Connection connection = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

and it always return null.

Comment: Mentioning your aim might help in getting more appropriate answers. What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 7):

`.unwrap()` should be the way to go, as written in [EclipseLink wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager).

I also used to get null when calling `em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);` because it was **not inside a transaction**. When called like this:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
java.sql.Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
// ...
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

everything works fine!

Answer (score 3):

```
java.sql.Connection connection = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

Should work, what version are you using?  Ensure that a transaction is active.

To get the data source name you should be able to use,

```
((JNDIConnector)em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class).getSession().getLogin().getConnector()).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://onpersistence.blogspot.com/2008/04/eclipselink-and-datasources.html) what I've found helpful:

```
private DataSource createDataSource() {
ClientDataSource dataSource = new ClientDataSource();
dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
dataSource.setPortNumber(1527);
dataSource.setDatabaseName("sample");
dataSource.setUser("app");
dataSource.setPassword("app");
return dataSource;
}

private EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
if (emf == null) {
  Map properties = new HashMap();
  properties
     .put(PersistenceUnitProperties.NON_JTA_DATASOURCE,createDataSource());
  emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU_NAME, properties);
}
return emf;
}
```

Can you create your datasource in the code, rather than configure via persistence.xml?

Comment: thanks Kyle. I already created a persistence.xml. is there a method something like: getEntityManger().getDataSourceName() in JPA/Eclipselink api?