# How to get jpa datasource properties from Entity Manager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager, jta

### Hi everybody

I was wondering if it's possible to get database connection properties through entity manager.

My persistence.xml looks like this

```
<persistence ...>
     <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="JTA">
          <jta-data-source>DatasourceForTestSystem</jta-data-source>
          <class> some.package.and.some.Class </class>
          ...
     </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I want something like

```
String host = em.getSomeFunction().getProperties().get("server");
String database = em.getSomeFunction().getProperties().get("database");
or
String url = em.getSomeFunction().getConnectionPool().getURL();
```

where url is something like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:5678:database`.
I'm using JDeveloper 12c with EclipseLink, an Oracle database and NO Hibernate.

Does somebody know how to get information about the connection properties?

Kind regards,

Stefi

### -- UPDATE --

@Kostja: thx again for your help but as I mentioned in my post I do not use Hibernate at all.

I already tried to use the Connection.class like this

```
java.sql.Connection conn = em.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class);
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046491/jpa-is-there-a-way-method-to-retrieve-persistence-unit-information). I always got a NPE for the Connection as well as for getSession() in this statement

```
((JNDIConnector)em.unwrap(JpaEntityManager.class)
    .getSession().getLogin().getConnector()).getName();
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046491/jpa-is-there-a-way-method-to-retrieve-persistence-unit-information).

I'm quiet confused why any of these solutions work for me. Maybe I'm missing something :-(

Answer (score 1):

The farthest you can go with JPA is to query the properties of the [`EntityManagerFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getProperties%28%29) or the [`Connection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html?is-external=true). The list of available properties varies between providers and between different version of a single provider.

Access the properties of the EMF like this:

```
Map<String,Object> props = emf.getProperties();
```

Getting your hands on the `Connection` is a bit more involved and depends on the JPA implementation. This could work for Hibernate, [courtesy @Augusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423930/how-to-retrieve-the-datasource-used-by-a-persistence-unit-programmatically):

cast the `EntityManagerFactory` to `HibernateEntityManagerFactory`,
 call `getSessionFactory()` and cast it to `SessionFactoryImpl`, call `getConnectionProvider()`

```
connectionProvder.getConnection();
```

Comment: I already tried this and only got three properties. None of them contained the neccessary information. That's why I was wondering if there is any other way to get host, port, database user or what else from Entity Manager :-(
But thanks anyway for your help :-)

Comment: @Stoffelchen - you could try the `Connection` interface, it is closer to the metal.

Comment: @Stoffelchen - my apologies for being less than helpful. I will leave my answer here as a warning for the posterity - this does not work. Do post and accept your solution once you have found one. You got my vote :)

Comment: Never mind :-) You were a great help. You showed me that I am at least on the right track!