# Get JTA DataSource properties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to get my DataSource properties, like user name or url.
This is my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="defaulttransaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Inside GlassFish 4.1, I have the required JDBC Resource and JDBC ConnectionPool, respectively `MyDataSource` and `MyDataSourceCP`.
If this is useful, MyDataSource is a `javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource` and MyDataSourceCP is a `oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource`.

MyDataSourceCP is configured with some parameters like URL, user name and password.
I would like to extract those properties from Java.

So far, I have tried the following:

1. [How to get jpa datasource properties from Entity Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704061/how-to-get-jta-datasource-properties-from-entity-manager)
2. [How to retrieve the datasource used by a persistence unit programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423930/how-to-retrieve-the-datasource-used-by-a-persistence-unit-programmatically)
3. [JPA - Is there a way/method to retrieve Persistence Unit information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046491/jpa-is-there-a-way-method-to-retrieve-persistence-unit-information)

But with no results.

As @Stoffelchen (in (1)), I would like something like

```
someObject.someMethod( ).getProperties( )
// or
someObject.someMethod( ).getProperties( "username" )
// or
someObject.someMethod( ).getUserName( )
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I am using Hibernate 4.3.

Thanks in advance